# return vector of enum

Tags: c++, вектор

```
enum class color{red,green, blue};
```

есть вот такой enum, я хочу его в вектор положить, а потом из функции вернуть

```
vector<color> getVectorFunc();
```

я не пойму как это сделать?

```
vector<color> getVectorFunc(){
   return //......//;
}
```

Comment: А чем это отличается от работы с вектором, скажем, из `int`? Как вариант, `return {color::red, color::green, color::blue};`.

Comment: а как я по выходу вектор получу?

Comment: Так же, как вы получали бы возвращенное значение любого другого типа. Например так: `std::vector<color> my_vec = getVectorFunc();`.

Comment: Что значит "не пойму как"??? Впишите ваш возвращаемый вектор в `return` - и все. В чем вопрос?

Comment: Вектор - предполагает "массив" (разновитность массива). Создаёте, наполняете - возвращаете. Т.е. там... а что есть? Тут три варианта решения как минимум.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не понимаю, [где проблема](https://ideone.com/YATvGX)?

```
#include <vector>

enum class color {red,green, blue};

std::vector<color> getVectorFunc() {
    std::vector<color> v {color::red,color::green, color::blue};
    return v;
    }

int main() {
    std::vector<color> v = getVectorFunc();
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Вот так можно **положить enum в контейнер std::vector и вернуть его из функции**. Только не забудьте библиотеку vector подключить.

```
enum color { red, green, blue }; // объявление перечисления

std::vector <color> getVectorFunc() // ф-я
{
    std::vector <color> Vec; // создаём вектор принимающий enum 
    color c; // создаём объект
    Vec.push_back(c); // метод push.back() добавляет переданный объект в конец вектора 
    return Vec; // возвращаем вектор
}

int main() 
{
    std::vector <color> getVectorFunc(); // вызов ф-ии возвращающей enum 
    return 0;
}
```

А в чём, собственно, проблема была?

Comment: `std::vector <color> getVectorFunc(); // вызов ф-ии возвращающей enum` Угу, как же :)

Comment: по-моему, это вообще не рабочий вариант

Comment: У вас в `main` нет никакого "вызова ф-ии".

Comment: даже если так написать
std::vector <color>res= getVectorFunc(); 
все равно работать не будет

Comment: ко всему прочему и color c  не инициализирован

Comment: @user9431986: Что именно "работать не будет"? "Работать не будет" - что это вообще значит?

Comment: ну в вектор мусор попадет

Comment: @user9431986: У вас вопрос о том, как вернуть вектор из функции. А о том, что именно в этом векторе должно содержаться, ни слова не сказано.

Comment: я знаю как вернуть вектор из функции, у меня был вопрос с enum один из участников сообщества дал ответ, он оказался не рабочим, я об этом сказал, в чем проблема?

Comment: @user9431986 Когда отвечаете кому-то (не под его вопросом/ответом), ставьте `@username` в начале. Иначе человек не получит уведомления и может не ответить.

Comment: *"в чем проблема"* Проблема в том, что про *"в вектор мусор попадет"* нужно было с самого начала в вопросе написать. И привести пример кода, в котором это происходит. Мы ж не телепаты.